# Is it possible to programmatically detect if is real or a virtual Android device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my Android application I have to use accelerometer and other sensors. Since this sensors aren't emulated by a Virtual Device, I've to use SensorSimulator project. The problem is that SensorSimulator's APIs look different from Android's ones. So I've to use different code if I'm in a real or in a virtual device. Does it exists a way to programmatically detect it? Or do you know other solutions?

Comment: see http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Answer (score 8):

You can try, by checking `Build.DEVICE` which for not real device shall read `generic` or check `Build.PRODUCT` which would be `sdk`.

Comment: You've made my day :)

Comment: Build.BRAND and Build.DEVICE can be "generic_x86" for x86 architecture, and Build.PRODUCT can be "sdk_google_phone_x86"

Answer (score 7):

The following is true for an emulator...

```
Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
```

or

```
boolean inEmulator = "generic".equals(Build.BRAND.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but just had the same issue. I modified Nermeen answer a bit as it doesn't work anymore:

```
boolean inEmulator = Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve this goal, such as:
(1) cat /proc/cpuinfo, emulator contains "goldfish", real devices contains "Qualcomm MSM xxxx",etc.
(2) features listed as follows show that it is an emulator:

```
private static String[] known_pipes={
        "/dev/socket/qemud",
        "/dev/qemu_pipe"
};

private static String[] known_qemu_drivers = {
        "goldfish"
};

private static String[] known_files = {
        "/system/lib/libc_malloc_debug_qemu.so",
        "/sys/qemu_trace",
        "/system/bin/qemu-props"
};

private static String[] known_numbers = { "15555215554", "15555215556",
        "15555215558", "15555215560", "15555215562", "15555215564",
        "15555215566", "15555215568", "15555215570", "15555215572",
        "15555215574", "15555215576", "15555215578", "15555215580",
        "15555215582", "15555215584", };

private static String[] known_device_ids = { 
        "000000000000000"// default ID on emulator
};
```

see the paper "Morpheus: Automatically Generating Heuristics to Detect Android Emulators" for more infomation.